# Smarty template engine - regex_replace any phone number with custom html

Tags: php, regex, smarty, smarty3, smarty2

My cms system (flynax.com) uses smarty template engine.

I have template that prints field value from database.

Tag used in template to print description field value (html) is:

```
{$item.value}
```

I need to hide any phone number from description field, and to do that I need to find any phone number in field output and replace it with this code:

```
<span class='telefon' data-last='REPLACED_VALUE'><span class='telefon2'>{$lang.click_here_to_show}</span></span>
```

I have jquery code that will be used to hide any phone number and show it on click (I also than track clicks with google analytics).

```
    {literal}

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.telefon').toggle(function() {
     $(this).find('span').text({/literal}'{$lang.click_here_to_show}'{literal});
      }, function() {
        $(this).find('span').text($(this).data('last'));
      }).click();
    });
  </script>
{/literal}
```

Code that I am trying and which trows me errors is:

```
{$item.value|regex_replace:"/([+]{0,1}[\d]{1,5}[\s]{0,1}[\/]{0,1}[(]{0,1}[\d]{0,3}[)]{0,1}\s{0,1}\d{2,4}[-]{0,1}[\s]{0,1}[\d]{2,4}[-]{0,1}[\s]{0,1}[\d]{1,4})$/gm":"<span class='telefon' data-last='$1'><span class='telefon2'>{$lang.click_here_to_show}</span></span>"}
```

test of my regex:
[check here](https://regex101.com/r/DTJd2m/1)

Can you suggest what I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot use `g` modifier, please remove, `m` is also redundant here. Also, there is no need to wrap the whole regex with a capturing group, you may access the whole match using `$0` backreference. Try `regex_replace:'/\+?\d{1,5}\s?\/?\(?\d{0,3}\)?\s?\d{2,4}-?\s?\d{2,4}-?\s?\d{1,4}/':"<span class='telefon' data-last='\$0'><span class='telefon2'>{$lang.click_here_to_show}</span></span>"`

Comment: What kind of error you getting ?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, I have tried your solution but it trows me bunch of errors like  `System error occurred
Smarty error: [in blocks/field_out_value.tpl line 39]: syntax error: unrecognized tag: $item.value|regex_replace:'/\+?\d{1,5 (Smarty_Compiler.class.php, line 465) line# 1095 file: /public_html/libs/smarty/Smarty.class.php
PHP version: 7.0.32-4+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 
System error occurred
Smarty error: [in blocks/field_out_value.tpl line 39]: syntax error: unrecognized tag '' (Smarty_Compiler.class.php, line 609)
line# 1095 file: /public_html/libs/smarty/Smarty.class.php`

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, when I test your regex, it selects only first occurrence: https://regex101.com/r/jYWQJq/1

Comment: In a regex tester, you [need to use `g`](https://regex101.com/r/jYWQJq/2), not in code.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew ok. and what about errors I get in smarty? Do we need to escape { and } inside regex or something else is causing error?

Comment: Maybe, try doubling them if the problem is due to the braces.